# What is the best way to handle nullable vals in Koltin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a function that accepts nullable Strings, but requires them to be non-null.

```
fun fn(a: String?) {
    if (a == null) {
        logger.warn("a is null, aborting")
        return
    }
    // do something
    fnThatDoesNotAcceptNulls(a)
}
```

Is there a better way to check if the value is null and `return` from the function in Kotlin?

Answer (score 3):

You can resolve this problem by:

0. using just `if` (your version)

```
fun fn(a: String?) {
    if (a == null) {
        logger.warn("a is null, aborting")
        return
    }
    // do something
    fnThatDoesNotAcceptNulls(a)
}
```

1. using just `if`

```
fun fn(a: String?) {
    if (a != null) {
        // do something
        fnThatDoesNotAcceptNulls(a)
        return
    }

    logger.warn("a is null, aborting")
}
```

2. using `if` (but without logging):

```
fun fn(a: String?) {
    if (a != null) {
        // do something
        fnThatDoesNotAcceptNulls(a)
    }
}
```

3. using `if-else`

```
fun fn(a: String?) {
    if (a == null) {
        logger.warn("a is null, aborting")
    } else {
        // do something
        fnThatDoesNotAcceptNulls(a)
    }
}
```

4. using `when` (with expression body - depends on return type!):

```
fun fn(a: String?) = when (a) {
    null -> {
        logger.warn("a is null, aborting")
    }
    else -> {
        // do something
        fnThatDoesNotAcceptNulls(a)
    }
}
```

5. using "elvis" (`?:`)

```
fun fn(a: String?) {
    val value = a ?: return
    
    // do something
    fnThatDoesNotAcceptNulls(value)
}
```

6. using `let` extension:

```
fun fn(a: String?) {
    a?.let {
        // do something
        fnThatDoesNotAcceptNulls(it)
    }
}
```

7. using `let` extension (with handling "negative" case when `a` is null):

```
fun fn(a: String?) {
    a?.let {
        fnThatDoesNotAcceptNulls(a)
    } ?: logger.warn("a is null, aborting")
}
```

8. using `run` extension:

```
fun fn(a: String?) {
    a?.run {
        // do something
        fnThatDoesNotAcceptNulls(this)
    }
}
```

9. using `run` extension (with handling "negative" case when `a` is null):

```
fun fn(a: String?) {
    a?.run {
        // do something
        fnThatDoesNotAcceptNulls(this)
    } ?: logger.warn("a is null, aborting")
}
```

In private, I like option 5 (with elvis) and those with extensions. But it all depends on the situation or the case.